# Ionic/Angular + Firebase with emulator on Android device = auth/network-request-failed

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I have to improve existing Ionic app using firebase as auth method for users login.
For my purpose i cannot touch existing list of previously registered users in production firebase app, I have to create new list locally using firebase emulator.
After adding and setup local auth & DB emulator extensions, I have added this into `app.module.ts`:

```
if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost') {
  firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099');
}
```

After continuing with adding new UI and logical features, using a web browser to test my work, I switch to the Android platform. After running the app and executing

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

I got the following error:

```
{
 "code": "auth/network-request-failed",
 "message": "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection, or unreachable host) has occurred."
}
```

It worked fine in the browser, but not on real device.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas on Android device

`window.location.hostname === 'localhost`

this will be executed

`firebase.auth().useEmulator('http://localhost:9099');`

so Firebase searching auth service on device on port 9099, that not exists, and produce such error.

To fix this just run in terminal

```
adb reverse tcp:9099 tcp:9099
```

Comment: It didn't worked.